# Forcing a string field to DateTime in WCF query with Azure Table Storage

Tags: node.js, wcf, azure, azure-table-storage

So, a quick overview of what I'm doing:
We're currently storing events to Azure Table storage from a Node.js cloud service using the "azure-storage" npm module. We're storing our own timestamps for these events in storage (as opposed to using the Azure defined one).

Now, we have coded a generic storage handler script that for the moment just stores all values as strings. To save refactoring this script, I was hoping there would be a way to tweak the query instead.

So, my question is, is it possible to query by datetime where the stored value is not actually a datetime field and instead a string?

My original query included the following:

```
.where( "_timestamp ge datetime'?'", timestamp );
```

In the above code I need to somehow have the query treat _timestamp as a datetime instead of a string...

Would something like the following work, or what's the best way to do it?

```
.where( "datetime _timestamp ge datetime'?'", timestamp );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, if the attribute type is `String` in an Azure Table, you can't convert that to `DateTime`. Thus you won't be able to use `.where( "_timestamp ge datetime'?'", timestamp );`

If you're storing your `_timestamp` in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` format, then you could simply do a string based query like

```
.where( "_timestamp ge '?'", timestamp );
```

and that should work just fine other than the fact that this query is going to do a full table scan and will not be an optimized query. However if you're storing in some other format, you may get different results.

Comment: My timestamps are stored in ISO format alright, but would "ge" work as expected here when comparing strings and not DateTimes?

Comment: Yes, it would work just fine as long as your timestamp values are in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` format.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles
Well I'll be damned. You learn something new everyday. That may work nicely. Granted its less efficient, but will get me over the hump. Thanks!